# Tips on reducing Silverlight server-side web application memory usage on server with limited Application Pool

Tags: silverlight, web-applications, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, application-pool

*For reference, I originally posted a version of this question on the Silverlight forum here:
http://forums.silverlight.net/p/190247/438343.aspx/1?p=True&t=634493619295498464

I would like to open it up to the SO community as it is still an issue for me.*

I'm using Silverlight 4 and WCF RIA services. My app is hosted with WinHost. The hosting package I have only allows an application pool size of 200mb before the app pool is auto-cycled.

The problem is that my app initialises at around 85mb and hits the 200mb limit with user activity. (Running queries, CRUD operations etc.)

So I really have two questions:

1. What are some tips for reducing the memory requirements of my app on the server?

   What could be using up all the memory on startup? (I don't run any queries at start-up just load a very minimal home page)
2. What should I look out for in order to minimise the growth in memory requirements of my server-side web app as users browse pages and run queries?

As sub-question, although I realise this is VERY subjective:

Is a 200Mb app pool too small for a small sivlerlight business app that is mainly user triggered CRUD operations?

(My testing has been with two users logged in concurrently)

This is my first Silverlight application so I don't have anything to compare it to.

Any information greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are focusing on Silverlight but that isn't all that relevant, its the WCF RIA Services that will be costing you the memory.  Since you ask whether 200MB is enough it implies you are in a position to change it.  My advice would be to change it, that will be a far cheaper way to solve this problem.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones To address your second point first, I could of course search for a hosting provider that would give me a larger memory allocation but that would cost me more money, (potentially a lot more), and also not address the original issue. I'm not sure how spending more money on hosting would be far cheaper than addressing the underlying issue? As for SL vs RIA, if it is RIA that is costing the memory then I would like to find a way of addressing this.

Comment: My comment indicated a belief that you were in a position to change the limit it turns out you aren't. Its helpful that when asking questions that we include details such as this so that such constraining factors are revealed